# create an modal popup containing reactive form and table using angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

halo i need help creating a modal popup that will contain a form(reactive) and a table to display all the information filled in the form
below is what i have tried, but when i view this on my app everything appears blank
hope someone can help
##main_app.component.ts

```
    openModal(){
      const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig()
      dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
      dialogConfig.id = 'report-btn';
      dialogConfig.height = "550px";
      dialogConfig.width = "450px";
      const modalDialog = this.dialog.open(ReportComponent, {data: {}});
    }
```

##modal-component.ts

```
  ReportForm : FormGroup
  reports : ReportData[]
  reportData: ReportData
  displayedColumns:string[] = ['Staff', 'Date', 'Period', 'Note']
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource([])

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ModalComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: ReportData[],
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
   
    ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.nurseReportForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      date: ['', [Validators.required]
    ],
    name:[
      '', [Validators.required]
    ],
    period:[
      '', [Validators.required]
    ],
    msg: [
      '',[Validators.required]
    ]

    })
    this.dataSource =new  MatTableDataSource(this.data)
  }

  onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.ReportForm.value)
    this.myService.postData(this.ReportForm.value)
    this.dialogRef.close({
      reportData : this.reports
    })
  }
```

##modal-component.html

```
<div id="myForm">
  <form [formGroup]="nurseReportForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  
    <mat-form-field class="form-field" appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Date</mat-label>
      <input matInput id="date" formControlName="date" [matDatepicker]="myDatepicker" required>
      <mat-datepicker-toggle [for]="myDatepicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #myDatepicker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field><br>
    <mat-form-field class="form-field" appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Period: </mat-label>
      <mat-select formControlName="period"  required>
        <mat-option value="Morning">Morning</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="Afternoon">Afternoon</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="Night">Night</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field><br>
    <mat-form-field class="form-field" appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Note:</mat-label>
      <textarea matInput cols="10" rows="10" ></textarea>
    </mat-form-field><br>
    <button mat-raised-button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
    
  </form>
</div>

<div>
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Staff">
      <th mat-header-cell *MatHeaderCellDef>Staff</th>
      <td mat-cell *MatCellDef="let element"> {{element.Staff}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Date">
      <th mat-header-cell *MatHeaderCellDef>Date</th>
      <td mat-cell *MatCellDef="let element">{{element.Date}}</td>
    </ng-container>
    
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Period">
      <th mat-header-cell *MatHeaderCellDef >Period</th>
      <td mat-cell *MatCellDef="let element">{{element.Period}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container> 
      <th mat-header-cell *matColumnDef>Note</th>
      <td mat-cell *MatCellDef="columnDisplay">{{element.Note}}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>>
    
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you add the ReportComponent as EntryComponent in your app module?

Comment: yes i added it to the entryComponent

Comment: In that case please create a [minimal reproducible example] .

Comment: it still not working 
i feeling the issue is with displaying the table in the popup
in the console this the error msg im getting 
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'template' of undefined
    at MatHeaderRowDef.extractCellTemplate

Comment: if you add a log statement in `ngOnInit` or `construtor` methods of the `ReportComponent` does that show up in the log. with this information, you can at least confirm that the component is getting initialized.

Comment: i've fixed this, but now my aim is to have the table display the info filled in the form
how can i pass the data from the form to the table in the same modal